# Fading In/Fading out audio towards the beginning and end of a song

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have an iTunes audio preview (30 seconds) that starts and stops abruptly. I'd like to add some easing to the audio where it fades in at the one second mark and fades at the 28 second mark. It fades in as it should but doesn't work in the `else if` conditional. What's going on?

**HTML**

```
<audio controls class="audio">
  <source src="http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/023/Music/0b/f7/f8/mzm.dehsezty.aac.p.m4a" type="audio/mp4" />
</audio>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $(".audio").prop("volume", 0.0);

  $(".audio").on("play", function() {
    if (this.currentTime < 2) {
      $(this).animate({volume: 1.0}, 500);
    } else if (this.currentTime > 27) {
      $(this).animate({volume: 0.0}, 500);
    }
});
```

I also noticed that I had to explicitly set the volume to 0 on the script side vs declaring the value as an attribute in the audio tag (no affect). I realize that its a property vs an attribute but is there a way to set a default value in the markup?

```
<audio controls class="audio" volume="0.0">
  <source src="http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/023/Music/0b/f7/f8/mzm.dehsezty.aac.p.m4a" type="audio/mp4" />
</audio>
```

Comment: The issue is that your event listener only fires once, so as far as your function is concerned, `currentTime` is always equal to `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your event listener from this:

```
$(".audio").on("play", function() {

});
```

To this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".audio").prop("volume", 0.0);
    $(".audio").on("timeupdate", function() {
        if (this.currentTime < 2) {
            $(this).stop().animate({volume: 1.0}, 1000);
        } else if (this.currentTime > 27) {
            $(this).stop().animate({volume: 0.0}, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

This way the `currentTime` variable will update constantly as the audio is playing.

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fakhkeo9/2/)

Comment: This works but two unforeseen problems occur. The first is once the song ends the volume goes back to 0, even if you click the play button again to restart the song. Also scurbbing through the audio throws the event off.

Comment: Change `$(this).animate` to `$(this).stop().animate()` [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fakhkeo9/2/)